# Sidekiq with workers connecting to different Redis instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

In my current project, there is a Redis Instance on Heroku and Sidekiq is configured to process jobs from that instance. We need to migrate the Redis instance to Azure and I wanted to use a configuration where one Worker connects to the Redis Instance on Heroku to process any queued jobs and the rest of the Workers connecting to the new instance on Azure to avoid any data loss.

I am new to Rails and Sidekiq. Please suggest a way for achieving the desired config

Comment: Take a look at the docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#connecting-to-redis ... You may want to consider Redis Cloud instead: https://redis.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/overview/

Comment: Mike Perham the creator of sidekiq has replied to this thread which may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020554/how-can-i-switch-redis-host-pool-in-sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

The [docs say](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#connecting-to-redis) that you can run this command to get the credentials:

```
heroku redis:credentials
```

Then get the connection string with:

```
heroku config:get REDIS_URL -a example-app
```

Then you can use the connection string from `REDIS_URL` to connect externally for a bit.

Comment: I want to do this programatically. Is there a way I can set the sidekiq client/server config so that the new jobs get enqueued to the new Redis server while the processing of the jobs can happen from both the old and the new Redis servers? @DogEatDog